# Rules for underscore usage in Higher Kinded Type parameters

Tags: scala, generics, wildcard, existential-type, higher-kinded-types

I wonder why the following works (note the Functor or Applicative are irrelevant for the example)

```
trait Functor[F[_]]
trait Applicative[F[_]] extends Functor[F]
```

But not

```
trait Functor[F[_]]
trait Applicative[F[_]] extends Functor[F[_]]
```

My issue is with **F vs F[_]**

What is the rule here ?

Especially the compiler gives a criptic error:

> F[_] takes no type parameters, expected: one

Comment: [Do the syntaxes for existential types and higher kinded types confuse you?](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/do-the-syntaxes-for-existential-types-and-higher-kinded-types-confuse-you/1403)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Underscore (`_`) has different meaning at the definition site (1) and at a call site (2).

(1) At the definition site underscore means that a generic (type parameter) is a type constructor (`* => *`) rather than a proper type (`*`).

```
trait A[X]                        // X is a proper type, *
//     ^^^ definition
trait B[X]   extends  A[X]        // X is a proper type, *
//     ^^^ definition, ^^^ call

trait A[F[_]]                     // F is a type constructor, * => *
//      ^^^^ definition
trait B[F[_]]   extends  A[F]     // F is a type constructor, * => *
//      ^^^^ definition,  ^^^ call
```

Since at the definition site it's already emphasized once that `F` is a type constructor, at a call site it's always referred to as just `F` (no need in extra `_` if you mean the same type constructor `F`).

(2) At a call site, for a type constructor (`* => *`) `F`, `F[_]` means an existential type. An existential type is a proper type (`*`).

```
trait A[X]                        // X is a proper type, *
//     ^^^ definition

trait B[F[_]]                     // F is a type constructor, * => *
                extends  A[F[_]]  // F[_] is an existential type, *
//      ^^^^ definition,   ^^^^ call
```

Comment: Stupid question but what would be the proper definition of call site for type. I got what you wrote above, but can generalize in my head makes a call site, a call site. Is it just in the case of extends ?

Comment: @MaatDeamon I meant everywhere where you refer to the type (except where it's defined). `extends A[X]`, `type T = X`, `foo[X]()`, `Bar[X]` etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74267610/polymorphic-method-works-with-type-lambda-but-not-with-type-wildcard-in-scala-3

Answer (score 3):

`trait Functor[F[_]]` means **Functor** requires a type constructor *(a type with a hole that produces a new type when the hole is filled)*.

Then, here `trait Applicative[F[_]] extends Functor[F]` you are saying that **Applicative** also requires something with one hole. Thus, `F` is already understood to be something with one hole and so passing it to **Functor** makes sense.

Finally, here `extends Functor[F[_]]` is the same as `extends Functor[F[T] forSome { type T } ]` so you are filling the hole in `F` and thus it is not longer applicable to **Functor**.

Answer (score 3):

There exists a [plan](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/wildcards.html) in Scala 3.2 (Dotty) to make `F[_]` mean the [same](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/5379) at both the definition site and call site

> In Scala 3.2, the meaning of _ changes from wildcard to placeholder
> for type parameter.

so the following would become valid syntax

```
trait Applicative[F[_]] extends Functor[F[_]] // Both F[_] represent type lambda [X] =>> F[X]
```

The intention is to replace wildcard (existential) type `F[_]` with `F[?]`. This is already visible in Dotty REPL

```
Starting dotty REPL...
scala> val l: List[_] = List(42)
val l: List[?] = List(42)
```

and if compiled with `source:3.1 -deprecation` the warning is already raised

```
dotc -source:3.1 -deprecation Main.scala
-- Deprecation Warning: Main.scala:2:14 ----------------------------------------
2 |  val l: List[_] = List(42)
  |              ^
  |        `_` is deprecated for wildcard arguments of types: use `?` instead
1 warning found
```

For this purpose kind-projector has [preemptively](https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector/pull/91) changed its type lambda syntax from `F[?]` to `F[*]` in order to free up `?` for Scala 3 existential type.

As a side note consider how the [kind](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/kind-polymorphism.html) of the type constructor can be expressed currently in Dotty

```
Starting dotty REPL...
scala> trait Functor[F <: [X] =>> Any]
     | trait Applicative[F <: [X] =>> Any] extends Functor[F]
// defined trait Functor
// defined trait Applicative

scala> trait Applicative[F <: [X] =>> Any] extends Functor[[X] =>> F[X]]
// defined trait Applicative
```

The kind `[X] =>> Any` is syntax proper akin to informal notation `* => *` mentioned by Dmytro above.